# What is the more pythonic way to handle variables?

Tags: python

In my case I have this class:

```
 class CSVUploader():                                                                                                                                          
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                               
         self.acc = kwargs['acc']                                                
         self.prod = kwargs['prod']                                              
         self.url_id = kwargs['url_id']                                          
         self.dest = kwargs['dest']                                              
         self.header = kwargs['header']                                          
         self.metadata = kwargs.copy()                                           
         self.table_name = '_'.join([self.prod, self.url_id])
```

This class holds a lot of information and does a lot of things based on whats inside `**kwargs`. Later on I will need to add more parameters to the dictionary (**kwargs) that I'm passing to this class. The thing is I don't really know if I will need to add 2 or 10 more parameters.

Right now I'm using `self.<variable>` when executing logic in this class. For example:

```
self.check_columns(self.table_name, self.header)
```

My other thought was to use `self.metadata['variable']` instead of `self....`. 
And finally my last thought was to create a separate class that will hold all the `self.header` and all of this. But in my code I will call it like this:

```
metadata = Metadata()
metadata.header
```

So there are plenty of ways to do it, what would be the most pythonic way. Plus I'm interesting in keeping my code logically separated, clean and easily readable.

Comment: You should consider using `__getattr__`. It would enable you to provide access to the attributes while keeping everything only in the `self.metadata`. I.e. you can provide a more user-friendly interface while keeping a simple and small implementation without many attributes. Later on you can modify the naive implementation of `__getattr__` to do more things (like computing "derived" attributes on the fly etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the variables in kwargs to the instance:

```
class CSVUploader():       
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Alternatively, you can use a named-tuple and change CSVUploader's methods into functions that act on it.

```
CSVUploader = collections.namedtuple('CSVUploader', list_of_variable_names)
```